idiomatic way to free all objects in case of failure
I have the following example function for creating an object:
long CreateFoo(Foo** out) {//Foo is only visible in this translation unit, it's an opaque struct in any other TU
    Foo* f = calloc(1, sizeof(Foo));
    if(!f) {
        return 0;
    }
    f->obj = CreateCOMObject(); // A Win32 COM object. it needs a special function call for memory cleanup
    if(!f->obj) {
        free(f);
        return 0;
    }
    f->obj2 = CreateObject2FromLibrary();
    if(!f->obj2) {
        IUnknown_Release(f->obj) // clean up the COM object
        free(f);
        return 0;
    }
    f->obj3 = calloc(1,sizeof(Object3));
    if(!f->obj3) {
        IUnknown_Release(f->obj); // clean up the COM object
        LibraryFree(f->obj2); // clean up using the library
        free(f);
        return 0;
    }
    // rinse repeat for each sub object
    *out = f;
    return 1;
}

as you can see, for each subobject, I need to check whether the creation/initialization succeeded and clean up more and more objects the further in we are in the function.
is there a more readable, idiomatic way (without macros) to shorten this function?
The example contains Win32 COM objects, but that is only for the sake of having an example where the clean up is not a simple free()

You can make a label called error after your return and do this: if(f->obj) IUnknown_Release(f->obj); for all pointers. You can then goto error on error and all your allocations will be freed.

Don't you also have a FreeFoo function that disposes of the object after you have finished with it? As long as it is robust (i.e. doesn't release null pointers) you can just call that.
